# Multiple UI files for Qt mobile app

Tags: c++, qt

I have multpile ui files .
I want to navigate througth them according to pushbutton clicks.

How can I control this in the code ?
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Each ui file generally has cpp class assotiated with it.

Just create it and show.

```
class myGuiClass: public QWidget{...}; // class assotiated with ui

void SomeOtherClass::onSomePushButtonClicked()
{
    myGuiClass* wnd= new myGuiClass(this);
    wnd->show();
}
```

Comment: should i shange something in the header file, or should i create another header file ?

Comment: you should include another form class. http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Mobile_Hands-on_Labs/Qt/HelloQt/05_03.html look here for forms structure in QT

Comment: it was not helpfull , i am having trouble creating another UI file in Qt Creator, it can not be seen in desing mode , am quite stuck can you help ?

Comment: i am not using creator, but i think it is something like "new- gui class"

Comment: cant i just do this 

void MainWindow:: SubmitClicked() {
 ui->setupUi(MainWindow1); }

to move from ui file to another ?

Comment: Dear Raiv , i would really appreciate it if u could send me an example where we transfer from one ui file to another , plz i want all the code , this is my email : karim.eltel@hotmail.com